# PhantomJs returns undefined for page.title

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

From PhantomJs console I typed

```
var page = require('webpage').create();page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {console.log(page.title);});
```

It doesn't print the page title but only undefined

Why ?

Comment: What is the value of `status`.. Also what is this `require` ? You're not exactly using as outlined.. : https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here and your question is not clear enough. 1) Don't confuse standalone PhantomJS and a bridge between node.js and PhantomJS. Those scripts are written entirely differently. 2) If you actually used the interactive mode (REPL) of standalone PhantomJS, then there is a bug which prevents you from loading any page. You will have to write a script. 3) A server side script doesn't need to be minified, so please don't write such a script in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly `require("webpage")` is not phantomJS' module, so that's incorrect.

Try use is as outlined in the documentation :

https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var sitepage = null;
var phInstance = null;
phantom.create()
    .then(instance => {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
    })
    .then(page => {
        sitepage = page;
        page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function(){
            console.log("Title : " + page.title);
        });
       return ;
    })
```

Comment: It's very lengthy for such a little goal : I wan't to do this in phantomjs console